# aria2c do not output result table

Tags: linux, progress-bar, aria2

I am downloading a file using `aria2c`. I would like to only display the "progress bar".

```
> aria2c -console-log-level=error LINK

[#508b8d 0.9GiB/0.9GiB(99%) CN:1 DL:76MiB]
Download Results:
gid   |stat|avg speed  |path/URI
======+====+===========+=======================================================
508b8d|OK  |    76MiB/s|/home/user/file

Status Legend:
(OK):download completed.
```

What I would like to have is this.

```
> aria2c args LINK

[#508b8d 0.9GiB/0.9GiB(99%) CN:1 DL:76MiB]
```

Is there a way to do that or do I have to recompile the program? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the advance options section: https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html#advanced-options

`--download-result=hide`

edit:

You maybe interested in `--summary-interval=0` too.